# Getting null object while passing object as parameters in wcf

Tags: wcf

Receiving null object while passing object as parameters in wcf

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetLoginInfo", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]       
 string ServiceLogin(LoginParam Para);

         public string ServiceLogin(LoginParam para)
                {
                    try
                    {
                     }
                 }
```

Comment: Add the front-end code

Comment: ensure that object has a similar name in the WCF function which is "para" and in JSON format

Comment: DO you have [DataContract] attribute added for the LoginParam  class and [DataMember] attribute added for the members?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide all related codes and review [how-to-create-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good an

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `BodyStyle` property, the request body will be determined whether including the name of the parameter.
Take the default WCF service application project as an example, there is a custom data contract class and operation contract.

```
  [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
}

   [OperationContract]
    CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);
```

The default BodyStyle value is `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`
For processing the Json body properly, the request body should be,

```
{"StringValue":"Hello","BoolValue":true}
```

[image]
If BodyStyle is `WebInvoke(BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)`
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.